# Is there a Package i need to install to get coeftest in R?

Tags: r, rstudio

I am trying to get the HC standard errors from a set of data using

```
coeftest(Partc, df = Inf, vcov = vcovHC(fm1, type = "HC1"))
```

but it returns the error:

```
Error in coeftest(Partc, df = Inf, vcov = vcovHC(fm1, type = "HC1")) : 
   could not find function "coeftest"
```

Am I missing the package required to do this?

Comment: [Here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lmtest/versions/0.9-37/topics/coeftest) is the first hit on a google search for "r function coeftest", suggesting you need to `install.packages("lmtest")`

Comment: There are several curious things about this code snippet and this function. While R partially matches arguments, the formal argument name is `vcov. = ` . One wonders why the function authors added a `.` maybe to avoid conflict with `stats::vcov` although they could override it entirely. Additionally, `?coeftest` tells us "[`vcov.` can be a] matrix or ... a function". Your code snippet fits a model `Partc` but you calculate the variance-covariance from `fm1`. Most likely this is a mistake and you could replace it with `vcov. = function(x) vcovHC(x, type='HC1')`.

Answer (score 7):

The package `lmtest` contains a function called `coeftest`, that seems to be what you are looking for.

Installing that package should solve your issue.

```
install.packages("lmtest")
```

Comment: don't forget to run `library("lmtest")` after you do the installation.  (Installation needs to be done only once per computer/R installation, `library()` needs to be done in each new session.) `install.packages("sos"); findFn("coeftest")` can help for these kinds of problems in the future.